# Using npm3 within a module unable to get parent node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Not sure if this is a known issue with `npm3` but because of the `npm3`'s flat module structure, from within a module, I cant locate `node_modules` using,

```
var node_modules = fs.readdirSync('node_modules');
```

Instead I have to use,

```
var node_modules = fs.readdirSync('../../node_modules');
```

to traverse up to find it. This obviously doesn't happen with npm2+ since the `node_modules` are nested within the packages.

Is there a way around this ? I searched every where for a better solution.

Comment: Why do you need to manually read the `node_modules` directory?

Comment: This is mainly needed to filter out the `node_modules` for webpack as I dont want to bundle any external modules. When I use the plugin `webpack-node-externals` to filter out the `node_modules` it doesnt seem to work with node 3+ from what i can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bad design. I'm not sure why do you need to locate `node_modules` manually; if you know that something was installed for sure, use `require.resolve()` builtin, that locates the package for you. Note you can `require.resolve()` not only `.js` files but also `package.json` of a desired package which is helpful for locating the root of the installed package.

Edit:

If you are trying to use webpack to bundle server code, you can define externals manually:

```
var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules') // this always exists
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  })
```

and then in webpack config:

```
externals: nodeModules,
```

Comment: I realize this is a bad design. But this is mainly needed to filter out the `node_modules` in the case of `webpack`. You can use the plugin `webpack-node-externals` to filter out the node_modules however it doesnt seem to work with node 3+ from what i can see.

Comment: That is my problem. Fs would throw an error saying node_modules doesnt exist

Comment: You mean, you don't have `node_modules` subdirectory in the main package directory? That sounds strange.

Comment: So in the main package there is `node_modules` however there is no `node_modules` in the sub module which has the webpack.config.